# Scaffolding a migration programatically in entity framework 5 code first

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a system which scaffolds a migration from inside our code using `ToolingFacade`.
The system worked fine in entity framework 4.3.1. After the Upgrade to 5.0 I see that the correct entity framework version is loaded when starting out tool, however when I call the scaffold method I get the following exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+ScaffoldRunner'
from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Does anyone know why calling a method in entity framework 5.0 requires an older version dll?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently when using EF6. Visual Studio required me to re-install EntityFramework via the Package Manage console to get things working again. Note that when I did so, the console output suggested that it had no idea that EF was installed before; somehow the association had been lost. Perhaps this is why the tooling assembly or assemblies weren't being loaded.

In any case, reinstalling the package via the console (and a restart of Visual Studio) solved the problem for me.